# Editing , posting and deleting appointments (Django)

Tags: django, validation, authentication, edit

I wrote a login page that is supposued to take appointments. Everything works except when it comes to making new post and editing them.here is the html page that is  giving me trouble.

```
`!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    <title>What's Up</title>
    <h1>Hello </h1>
    <p>Here are your appointments for today</p>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/create">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jojos Bizaree Adventure</td>
                    <td>11:00PM</td>
                    <td>Done</td>
                    <td><a href="/edit">Edit</a>
                    <a href="/delete">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </form>
        <p>Your other appointments</p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {%for appt in appts%}
                <td>Task:{{appts.task}}</td>
                <td>Date:{{appts.date}}</td>
                <td>Time:{{appts.time}}</td>
                <td><p><a href="/edit">Edit</a></p>
                <td><a href="/delete">Delete</a></td>
                {% endfor %}   

            </tbody>

        </table>
        <form action="/update" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>Add Appointment:</p>
            <button type="submit" value="addappoint">Add</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>'
```

I want to be able to add information from this page to the table

```
    enter code here<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Update Appointment</title>
        <a href="appointments.html">Dashboard</a> ||<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/create" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Task: <input type="text"></p>

        <p>Status: <input type="radio">Done<br>
                   <input type="radio">Pending<br>
                   <input type="radio">Missed<br>
        </p>
        <p>Date: <input type="date"></p>
        <p>Time:<input type="time"></p>
        <button type="submit" value="newappoint">Update</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and edit the data in question with this page

```
`<!DOCTPYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
       <h1>Edit Appointment</h1>
       <a href="/success">Dashboard</a> ||<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="/sucess" method="POST">
                <table>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <form action="/sucess" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <p>Edit Appointment</p>
                                <p>Date: <input type="date" name="date"></p>
                                <p>Time: <input type="time" name="time"></p>
                                <p>Task: <input type="text" name="task">
                                </p>
                                <button type="submit" value="addappoint">Edit</button>
                            </form>



                </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
    </body>

    </html>`
```

ive tried putting the input in a context dictionary and that didn't work. 
here are the django files where I think the problem lies.

Here are my urls

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views .index),
    url(r'^register$', views .register),
    url(r'^login$',views.login),
    url(r'^success$', views.success),
    url(r'^new$', views.new),
    url(r'^logout$',views.logout),
    url(r'^delete$',views.delete),
    url(r'^edit$',views.edit),
    url(r'^create$', views.create),
    url(r'^update$',views.update)
]
```

and here are my views

```
   enter code here# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
import bcrypt
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    #appt=Appt.objects
    context ={
    #"appts": appt
    }

    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def register(request):
    errors = User.objects.validate(request.POST)
    #print 'this process works', request.POST
    if len(errors) > 0:
        for error in errors:
            messages.error(request, error)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        hashpwd = bcrypt.hashpw(request.POST["password"].encode(), bcrypt.gensalt())
        newuser = User.objects.create(
            first_name=request.POST['first_name'],
            last_name=request.POST['last_name'],
            email=request.POST['email'],
            password=hashpwd)

        request.session['userid'] = newuser.id
        request.session['name'] = newuser.first_name
        print "session info", newuser.id, newuser.first_name
        return redirect("/success")

def login(request):
    # print postData['email']
    errors = User.objects.login(request.POST)

    if len(errors) > 0:
        for error in errors:
            messages.error(request, error)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'])[0]
        request.session['userid'] = user.id
        request.session['name'] = user.first_name
        return redirect("/success")

def success(request):
    user = request.session['userid']
    return render(request, 'appointments.html')

def logout(request):
    request.session.clear()
    #print 'goodbye'
    return redirect('/')   
def new(request):
    request.session
    return render(request,'newappoint.html')
def delete(request):
    return (request,'destroy')
def edit(request):
    return render(request,'edit.html')
def create(request):
    return redirect('edit.html')
def update(request):
    return render(request,'newappoint.html')
```

Comment: for first 2  html code form action path is create, I think change 2nd form action to update and in create instead of return redirect('edit.html') do render and pass form data

Comment: I suggest you use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/